# Bad Request Error when execute waitForBackgroundJavaScript() method with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm using a htmlunit to scrapping a webpage.

```
HtmlPage p = webClient.getPage(URL);
HtmlElement b = p.getFirstByXPath("xpath selector1");
HtmlPage a = b.click();
a.executeJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0, 6000);");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
```

My requirement is when open a page I have to do a click on a filtering button.
The data is updated but the page is lazy loading, so I need to simulate scrolling to the bottom of the page to get more items. When a scroll is done a background request is executed by the server and retrieve more data.

I have a `WebConnectionWrapper` where catch the background request/response.

But an `400 Bad Request for URL` error appear when I add this line on my code because I need to wait for a javascript scroll execution.

```
 webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
```

And without this line the request is done without any problem.

What could be the problem when add a `waitForBackgroundJavaScript()` ?

Comment: To find the reason and fix it i need more details. Please one an issue at https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues and i will try to help.